# Invalid authorization specification error using FILEDSN on OleDBConnection

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, odbc, oledbconnection

I was trying to compile the simple following program but it throws the error "Invalid authorization specification". I searched google for it and there is nothing may be someone can give me a hint on how to debug this.

```
  OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
  con.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;FILEDSN=C:\\Path\\to\\my\\file.dsn";
  con.Open();
```

the file is in the right location and it is generated automatically by the tools given by microsoft. I got the same error ever if the location of the file is wrong. Also, when using "Data Source" instead of "FILEDSN" it works as expected. I am using Windows authentication.

Comment: yes, it includes them. but as I said, It gives me the error even it the file location is not correct. the file is automatically generated  with the first property.

Comment: I thought file DSNs could only be used with ODBC (including the MSDASQL OLE DB provider for ODBC drivers).

Comment: You url start with two backslashes so it must include the server. I would put the URL in a file explorer and see if you are able to get the file.  The folder has to be in a shared folder.

Comment: well, as I said It does not care if the url is right or wrong. it always throuws the same error. Here, It was a garbage path.